# Database Query for Multiple Instances

Tags: sql, database

I have a database table of all US zip codes and their corresponding state and congressional district like this below..

```
id | zipcode | state_abbr | district
 1     30080      GA           1
 2     30080      TN           2
```

I need a query that will return any zipcodes that show up in more than one state. How can I do this?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: what DB is this? MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT zipcode 
FROM (
       SELECT zipcode 
       FROM temp
       GROUP BY zipcode, state_abbr 
     ) AS t 
GROUP BY zipcode 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this sql.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2fcb4/1)

**MySQL 5.5.30 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`id` int, `zipcode` int, `state_abbr` varchar(2), `district` int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`id`, `zipcode`, `state_abbr`, `district`)
VALUES
    (1, 30080, 'GA', 1),
    (2, 30080, 'TN', 2)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select zipcode
from Table1
group by zipcode
having count(zipcode)>1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2fcb4/1/0)**:

```
| ZIPCODE |
-----------
|   30080 |
```

Comment: But that only shows how many show up more than once... perhaps it shows up more than once PER STATE... which means you need to only count single instances per state and then look to duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.zipcode 
  FROM zipcode x 
  JOIN zipcode y 
    ON y.zipcode = x.zipcode 
   AND y.id < x.id;
```